# How do I use free to deallocate heap allocations made using malloc?

Tags: c, dynamic, memory-leaks, malloc

I've encountered an issue with heap deallocation using `free()` in my tokenizer.  The tokenizer is part of a recursive descent parsing calculator, which works flawlessly otherwise.  But upon incorporation of a call to the deallocation function, it behaves erratically. While realistically, the calculator will likely never come close to exhausting its heap, writing a program with a memory leak is just poor practice.

**tokenize.h**

```c
#define OPERAND 0
#define OPERATOR 1
#define PARENTHESIS 2
#define TERMINAL 3
#define ADD '+'
#define SUBTRACT '-'
#define MULTIPLY '*'
#define DIVIDE '/'
#define EXPONENT '^'
#define L_PARENTHESIS '('
#define R_PARENTHESIS ')'

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *value;
} token;

int token_count();
token *tokenize();
void deallocate();
```

**tokenize.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tokenize.h"

int token_count(char string[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9') {
            while (1) {
                i++;
                if (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9') {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        switch (string[i]) {
          case ADD:
          case SUBTRACT:
          case MULTIPLY:
          case DIVIDE:
          case EXPONENT:
          case L_PARENTHESIS:
          case R_PARENTHESIS:
            count++;
            i++;
            continue;
          default:
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

token *tokenize(char string[]) {
    int i = 0;
    token *ret;
    int count = token_count(string);
    if (!count) {
        return ret;
    }
    ret = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(token));
    ret[count].id = TERMINAL;
    int ret_ind = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9') {
            ret[ret_ind].id = OPERAND;
            int size = 0;
            int j = i;
            while (1) {
                size++;
                j++;
                if (string[j] >= '0' && string[j] <= '9') {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1);
            ret[ret_ind].value[size + 1] = '\0';
            for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                ret[ret_ind].value[k] = string[i + k];
            }
            i = j;
            ret_ind++;
            continue;
        }
        switch (string[i]) {
          case ADD:
          case SUBTRACT:
          case MULTIPLY:
          case DIVIDE:
          case EXPONENT:
            ret[ret_ind].id = OPERATOR;
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            ret[ret_ind].value[0] = string[i];
            ret[ret_ind].value[1] = '\0';
            ret_ind++;
            i++;
            continue;
          case L_PARENTHESIS:
            ret[ret_ind].id = PARENTHESIS;
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            ret[ret_ind].value[0] = L_PARENTHESIS;
            ret[ret_ind].value[1] = '\0';
            ret_ind++;
            i++;
            continue;
          case R_PARENTHESIS:
            ret[ret_ind].id = PARENTHESIS;
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            ret[ret_ind].value[0] = R_PARENTHESIS;
            ret[ret_ind].value[1] = '\0';
            ret_ind++;
            i++;
            continue;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}

void deallocate(token *in) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        free(in[i].value);
        i++;
        if (in[i].id == TERMINAL) {
            break;
        }
    }
    free(in);
    return;
}
```

Comment: replace `while(1) {` with  `while (in[i].id != TERMINAL)` in `deallocate` function. What if your `in` array is empty or have only one entry?

Comment: I really don't understand how this code can work even in simple situation...

Comment: This is hardly a [mcve] ... emphasizing the **minimality**.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Consider using Linux because it has them

Comment: OT:  regarding the calls to `malloc()` .  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in case the input line has no tokens or a syntax error, you return `ret` uninitialized from `tokenize`. You should return `NULL` instead.
- `ret[ret_ind].value[size + 1] = '\0';` stores the null terminator one step too far in the allocated array. It should be `ret[ret_ind].value[size] = '\0';`
- `malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1)` is inconsistent: if you insist on using `sizeof(char)`, which is `1` by definition, you should write `malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char))`, but it is idiomatic to use `malloc(size + 1)` in C and you could also replace multiple lines of code with a simple `ret[ret_ind].value = strndup(string + i, k);`
- the cases for `L_PARENTHESIS` and `R_PARENTHESIS` could be merged into a single block.
- the deallocation loop should stop when you reach the `TERMINAL` token. As currently coded, you cannot handle an empty list, which you should not produce, but it is better to make utility functions more resilient to later changes.

  ```
  void deallocate(token *in) {
      if (in) {
          for (int i = 0; in[i] != TERMINAL; i++)
              free(in[i].value);
          free(in);
      }
  }
  ```
- the prototypes in **token.h** should include the typed argument lists.

Here is a simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tokenize.h"

int token_count(const char *string) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        switch (string[i++]) {
          case ' ':
            continue;
          case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
          case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            i += strspn(string + i, "0123456789");
            continue;
          case ADD:
          case SUBTRACT:
          case MULTIPLY:
          case DIVIDE:
          case EXPONENT:
          case L_PARENTHESIS:
          case R_PARENTHESIS:
            count++;
            continue;
          default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

token *tokenize(const char *string) {
    int count = token_count(string);
    if (count <= 0)
        return NULL;

    token *ret = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(token));
    int i = 0;
    int ret_ind = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9') {
            int size = strspn(string + i, "0123456789");
            ret[ret_ind].id = OPERAND;
            ret[ret_ind].value = strndup(string + i, size);
            ret_ind++;
            i += size;
            continue;
        }
        switch (string[i]) {
          case ' ':
            i++;
            continue;
          case ADD:
          case SUBTRACT:
          case MULTIPLY:
          case DIVIDE:
          case EXPONENT:
            ret[ret_ind].id = OPERATOR;
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(2);
            ret[ret_ind].value[0] = string[i];
            ret[ret_ind].value[1] = '\0';
            ret_ind++;
            i++;
            continue;
          case L_PARENTHESIS:
          case R_PARENTHESIS:
            ret[ret_ind].id = PARENTHESIS;
            ret[ret_ind].value = malloc(2);
            ret[ret_ind].value[0] = string[i];
            ret[ret_ind].value[1] = '\0';
            ret_ind++;
            i++;
            continue;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    ret[ret_ind].id = TERMINAL;
    return ret;
}

void deallocate(token *in) {
    if (in) {
        for (int i = 0; in[i] != TERMINAL; i++)
            free(in[i].value);
        free(in);
    }
}
```

Here are additional remarks for the rest of the code:

- why clear the screen on entry and exit?
- you should test for end of file in the main loop:

  ```
  if (!fgets(user_in, 1024, stdin))
      break;
  ```
- you should strip the newline efficiently:

  ```
  #include <string.h>

  user_in[strcspn(user_in, "\n")] = '\0';
  ```
- then you can simplify the test for exit:

  ```
  if (!strcmp(user_in, "exit"))
      break;
  ```
- no need to clear `user_in` after `solve()`
- you could simplify testing by solving the command line arguments:

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
      solve(argv[i]);
  ```
- you should ignore white space and accept empty lines
- you should use `"%.17g` instead of `%lf`. Note that the `l` is mandatory
  for `scanf()` for a `double` type, but ignored for `printf`, because
  `float` arguments are converted to `double` when passed to vararg 
  functions like `printf`.
- you should use a context structure and pass a pointer to it
  to `parse` and its helper functions to avoid global variables
- as you can see in `try_add_sub` and `try_mul_div`, it would simplify
  the switch to unify token types and avoid the `OPERATOR` classification.
- the parser is too complicated: you should use recursive descent more
  directly: `try_add_sub` should first call `try_mul_div` and iterate on
  additive operators, calling `try_mul_div` for each subsequent operand.
  Similarly, `try_mul_div` should first call `try_exp` and `try_exp` would
  call `try_primitive` which would handle parentheses and constants.
- this approach consumes one token at a time, which can be read from
  the expression source on the fly, bypassing the need for tokenizing the whole string.
- you should accept the full number syntax for constants, which is easy with `strtod()`.

Here is a simplified version along these directions:

```c
//---- tokenize.h ----

#define TERMINAL 0
#define OPERAND 1
#define ERROR 2
#define ADD '+'
#define SUBTRACT '-'
#define MULTIPLY '*'
#define DIVIDE '/'
#define EXPONENT '^'
#define L_PARENTHESIS '('
#define R_PARENTHESIS ')'

#define SYNTAX_ERROR 1
#define PAREN_ERROR 2

typedef struct context {
    char *p;
    char *nextp;
    int parenthesis_balance;
    int error_code;
    double value;
} context;

int this_token(context *cp);
void skip_token(context *cp);

//---- tokenize.c ----

#include <stdlib.h>

//#include "tokenize.h"

int this_token(context *cp) {
    char *p = cp->p;
    for (;;) {
        switch (*p) {
        case '\0':
            cp->nextp = p;
            return TERMINAL;
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\n':
            /* ignore white space */
            p++;
            continue;
        case ADD:
        case SUBTRACT:
        case MULTIPLY:
        case DIVIDE:
        case EXPONENT:
        case L_PARENTHESIS:
        case R_PARENTHESIS:
            /* single character operators */
            cp->nextp = p + 1;
            return *p;
        default:
            /* try and parse as a number constant */
            cp->value = strtod(p, &cp->nextp);
            if (cp->nextp > p)
                return OPERAND;
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
}

void skip_token(context *cp) {
    cp->p = cp->nextp;
}

//---- parse.h ----

int parse(char expression[], double *result);
void solve(char expression[]);

//---- parse.c ----

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//#include "tokenize.h"
//#include "parse.h"

/* expression parsers return non zero upon error */
int try_add_sub(context *cp, double *result);
int try_mul_div(context *cp, double *result);
int try_exp(context *cp, double *result);
int try_primary(context *cp, double *result);

int try_add_sub(context *cp, double *result) {
    if (try_mul_div(cp, result))
        return 1;
    for (;;) {
        double operand;
        switch (this_token(cp)) {
        case ADD:
            skip_token(cp);
            if (try_mul_div(cp, &operand))
                return 1;
            *result += operand;
            continue;
        case SUBTRACT:
            skip_token(cp);
            if (try_mul_div(cp, &operand))
                return 1;
            *result -= operand;
            continue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int try_mul_div(context *cp, double *result) {
    if (try_exp(cp, result))
        return 1;
    for (;;) {
        double operand;
        switch (this_token(cp)) {
        case MULTIPLY:
            skip_token(cp);
            if (try_exp(cp, &operand))
                return 1;
            *result *= operand;
            continue;
        case DIVIDE:
            skip_token(cp);
            if (try_exp(cp, &operand))
                return 1;
            *result /= operand;
            continue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int try_exp(context *cp, double *result) {
    if (try_primary(cp, result))
        return 1;
    if (this_token(cp) == EXPONENT) {
        double operand;
        skip_token(cp);
        if (try_exp(cp, &operand))
            return 1;
        *result = pow(*result, operand);
    }
    return 0;
}

int try_primary(context *cp, double *result) {
    switch (this_token(cp)) {
    case OPERAND:
        skip_token(cp);
        *result = cp->value;
        return 0;
    case L_PARENTHESIS:
        skip_token(cp);
        cp->parenthesis_balance++;
        if (try_add_sub(cp, result))
            return 1;
        cp->parenthesis_balance--;
        if (this_token(cp) != R_PARENTHESIS) {
            cp->error_code = PAREN_ERROR;
            return 1;
        }
        skip_token(cp);
        return 0;
    }
    cp->error_code = SYNTAX_ERROR;
    return 1;
}

/* parse and evaluate an expression, return error code, update result */
int parse(char expression[], double *result) {
    context cc;
    cc.nextp = cc.p = expression;
    cc.parenthesis_balance = 0;
    cc.error_code = 0;
    cc.value = 0;
    if (try_add_sub(&cc, result))
        return cc.error_code;
    if (this_token(&cc) != TERMINAL)
        return SYNTAX_ERROR;
    return 0;
}

void solve(char expression[]) {
    double result = 0;

    switch (parse(expression, &result)) {
    case 0:
        printf("   %.17g\n", result);
        break;
    case SYNTAX_ERROR:
        printf("ERROR: Syntax\n");
        break;
    case PAREN_ERROR:
        printf("ERROR: Unbalanced parenthesis\n");
        break;
    }
}

//---- calculator.c ----

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//#include "parse.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        solve(argv[i]);
    if (argc == 1) {
        char user_in[1024];
        char *p;
        printf("Terminal Calculator\n");
        printf("Type 'exit' to terminate\n\n");

        for (;;) {
            printf("=> ");
            if (!fgets(user_in, sizeof user_in, stdin)) {
                printf("\n");
                break;
            }
            /* strip trailing newline */
            user_in[strcspn(user_in, "\n")] = '\0';
            /* skip initial white space */
            p = user_in + strspn(user_in, " \t");
            /* ignore empty and comment lines */
            if (*p == '\0' || *p == '#')
                continue;
            /* trap exit command */
            if (!strcmp(p, "exit"))
                break;
            solve(p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```